# Subreport visibility based on field and parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a main page with many subreports but dependent on the client parameter I don't want all pages to show. I have a dataset 'params' that indicate if each subreprt should be visible fot the Client picked based on a 1 or 0 in the field of the name of the report.

I used the below but then had the error that I hadn't used an aggregate

```
=iif(Fields!ClientName.Value,"params") = Parameters!Client.Value and (Fields!Overview.Value,"params") = "1" , TRUE, FALSE
```

I added in First around the fields but then it will only look at the first Client in the params table. I just want the correct subreports to be visable based on the Client chosen in the parameter

Comment: Try `=IIf(Parameters!Client.Value = 1, False, True)` for the `Visibility` property.

Comment: My parameter is a string i.e. the client name

Comment: `=IIf(Parameters!Client.Value = Fields!ClientName.Value AND Parameters!Overview.Value = "1", False, True)`

Comment: Sorry that just hides the subreport for every client then